# App works fine when running from Android Studio but crashes when signed apk installed

Tags: java, android

I have an app that pulls data from a PHP file and then parses the JSON return and puts the data in a list. When running the app from Android studio on my phone plugged in via USB, the app works 100%. However, when I built a signed version of the app, the activity no longer works. So the app opens, and I can enter a number in the search field, but when I tap submit which runs the activity, the app crashes.

Activity Code:

```
    package com.*.*;

    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    public class ViewBalances extends AppCompatActivity {
        private String TAG = ViewBalances.class.getSimpleName();

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private ListView lv;

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_balances);

            contactList = new ArrayList<>();

            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

            new GetContacts().execute();
        }

        /**
         * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
         */
        private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Showing progress dialog
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewBalances.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

                Intent inte = getIntent();
                String memnum = inte.getExtras().getString("membernumber_input");

                // Making a request to url and getting response
                String url = "****";
                String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url +memnum);

                Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");

                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                            String Savings_Amount = c.getString("Savings_Amount");
                            String name = c.getString("name");
                            String member_number = c.getString("member_number");
                            String phone_office = c.getString("phone_office");

                            // tmp hash map for single contact
                            HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            contact.put("Savings_Amount", Savings_Amount);
                            contact.put("name", name);
                            contact.put("CellNo", phone_office);
                            contact.put("member_number", member_number);

                            // adding contact to contact list
                            contactList.add(contact);
                        }
                    } catch (final JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                // Dismiss the progress dialog
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        ViewBalances.this, contactList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "Savings_Amount", "member_number", "CellNo"}, new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.Savings_Amount, R.id.member_number, R.id.CellNo});

                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        }
    }
```

Hope someone can help me...? Please?

Error:

```
    09-21 13:20:41.814 13880-13880/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                       Process: com.caliber.caliberclinicalconsultants, PID: 13880
                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method ViewBalResult(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'submit'
                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:321)
                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:280)
                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                                                           at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
    09-21 13:20:41.824 776-1626/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.caliber.caliberclinicalconsultants/.MainActivity
```

Comment: Where the stacktrace? What's the error?

Comment: Did you enable Proguard?

Comment: Can you post the error? Also please post the Manifest

Comment: if you have enabled the proguard just disable it and take a release version and try

Comment: I'm not using Proguard. Please see stack trace below:

Comment: Post edited with error message. The method ViewBalResult does exist in the main activity..

Comment: type Viewbalresult code

Comment: And post `activity_view_balances.xml`

Answer (score 1):

In most cases the reason is the `Proguard`.
You have to check you proguard file and classes you use.

Comment: Nope, not using proguard

Answer (score 1):

Update your Proguard file with following code.

```
-keepclassmembers class com.dom925.com.example.MyApp {
   public *;
}

-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,Signature
-keep class com.parse.*{ *; }
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application

-keep class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
    private *;
    void set*(***);
    *** get*();
}
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.example.MyApp.** { *; }
```